# Angular 2/4+ Router animation, wait for previous route animation to complete

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

I have the following animation configured on 2 of my routes.

```
trigger('routeAnimation', [
        transition(':enter', [
            style({ opacity: 0 }),
            animate('1s', style({ backgroundColor: 1 }))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
            style({ backgroundColor: 1 }),
            animate('1s', style({ backgroundColor: 0 }))
        ]),
    ]),
```

They work properly. Both get executed when switching from route A to B. However they execute simultaneously. I would like for the TO route to wait for the FROM route's exit animation to finish before coming in.

I want A to completely fade out before B comes in.

Is that possible? Maybe with lifecycle hooks or something?

Answer (score 2):

To wait for the leaving route's animation to finish before the entering route's animation begins:

```
const fadeIn = [
  query(':leave', style({ opacity:1 })),
  query(':enter', style({ opacity:0 })),
  query(':leave', animate('200ms', style({ opacity:0 }))),
  query(':enter', animate('200ms', style({ opacity:1 })))
]
```

...

```
trigger('routerAnimations', [
      transition('route1 => route2', fadeIn)
]
```

The animations will play in sequence.

(Updated after suggesting to delay the entering route by the duration of the leaving route, leading to a verbose solution)

Comment: Say I have a state C without an exit transition, or with an exit transition of only .5s, this would mean going to state A, C would fade out, A would wait .5s, then fade in.

Is there a way to go around something like that?

Comment: Sure. I've updated my response to show some approaches that should work if I understand you correctly. Let me know if they don't clear things up.

Comment: This still looks very filthy to me. But I suppose this is currently the only way possible. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I'll keep looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the skepticism! After digging back into things, here's a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Hey, you are most welcome ;) I'm not sure how your above example works, but it looks much cleaner. I will try it when I have the time. Thanks again!