# How to wait for animation to end before navigating to next route?

Tags: angular

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347953/angular-2-4-router-animation-wait-for-previous-route-animation-to-complete) solution but it does not seem to work for me.

What I did was (more or less) implement the code from [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Uo1coU9i1GsB1I4U3809?p=preview) into my client. However, I am coming from another route. I want to navigate from `/login` to `/home`.

`/login` does have some animations itself:

**login.animation.ts**

```js
import {
  sequence, trigger, stagger, animate, style, group, query as q, transition, keyframes, animateChild,
  state
} from '@angular/animations';
const query = (s,a,o={optional:true})=>q(s,a,o);

export const listAnimation = trigger('listAnimation', [
  transition(':enter, :leave', [
    query('.container', style({opacity: 0}), {optional: true}),
    query('.container', stagger('300ms', [
      animate('1s ease-in', keyframes([
        style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-75%)', offset: 0}),
        style({opacity: .5, transform: 'translateY(35px)', offset: 0.3}),
        style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)', offset: 1.0})
      ]))]), {optional: true})    
  ])
]);
```

**login.component.ts**

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../../service/authentication.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {NGXLogger} from 'ngx-logger';
import {listAnimation} from './login.animation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  animations: [
    listAnimation
  ],
  host: {
    '[@listAnimation]': ''
  }
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  public loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: [null, Validators.required],
    email: [],
    password: [null, Validators.required],
    passwordConfirm: [null, Validators.required]
  });

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient,
              private router: Router, private logger: NGXLogger,
              private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.logger.debug('Already logged in. Goto /home.');
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
  }

  onSubmit(): void {   
    this.onLoginSuccess();
  }

  onCancel(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

  private onLoginSuccess(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
}
```

Here I want `/home` to wait until `/login` has finished.

In **router.animation.ts** I have the animations you saw in the first example plus the suggestion `transition('route1 => route2', animations)` from the second one:

```js
import {
  sequence, trigger, stagger, animate, style, group, query as q, transition, keyframes, animateChild,
  state
} from '@angular/animations';
import {listAnimation} from './component/login/login.animation';
const query = (s,a,o={optional:true})=>q(s,a,o);

export const routerTransition = trigger('routerTransition', [
  transition('* => *', [
    query(':leave', animateChild()),          
    query(':enter', animateChild())
  ]),

  transition('login => home', listAnimation)
]);
```

Everything works *except* the fact, that `/home` does not wait. As `/login` executes its animations, `/home` just pops right in and messes up the scene.

Obviously I'm missing something - what do I have to add in order to make this work?

---

**Using `CanDeactivate`**

Extending **login.component.html** such that I can listen to animation events:

```xml
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [@listAnimation]="3"
        (@listAnimation.start)="animationStart($event)"
        (@listAnimation.done)="animationDone($event)">
```

as well as in **login.component.cs**

```js
animationStart() {
  console.log('START');
}

animationDone() {
  console.log('END');
}

canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  console.log('login.component.ts canDeactivate()');
  return this.animationsDoneSource.asObservable();
}
```

The problem is that the animation is not getting executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the animations in your component to finish before proceeding with the navigation, you should implement `CanDeactivate` guard. Add observable to your component which emits after all the animations finish (you can listen to `.done` event for all animations), and use it in the `CanActivate` guard.

**login.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  animations: [
    listAnimation
  ],
  host: {
    '[@listAnimation]': ''
  }
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  private animationsDoneSource = new Subject<boolean>();

  @HostListener('@listAnimation.done') onDone() {
     this.animationsDoneSource.next();
     this.animationsDoneSuorce.complete();
  }

  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.animationsDoneSource.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**login.guard.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoginCanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<LoginComponent> {

  canDeactivate: Observable<boolean>(
    component: LoginComponent,
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return component.canDeactivate();
  }
}
```

**login-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canDeactivate: [LoginCanDeactivateGuard],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [LoginCanDeactivateGuard],
})
export class LoginRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Hmm, but is the code I am using that different? I do have a very similar looking `routerTransition` in **router.animation.ts** - still this is not working for me. Could a nested `<router-outlet>` be a problem here?

Comment: Remove  `group` from your animations. If you want your animations to run in sequence, you should not use the `group` method. It will execute your animations in parallel.

Comment: Okay, I commented that out but the result is the same. :/  I updated the code in my question - I just removed the `group(..)` completely.

Comment: After some digging I found that what I want can't be done with what I have so far. It would seem that the `CanDeactivate` story is the one I am looking for. Any chance you can elaborate that part of your answer?

Comment: Sure, give me a moment

Comment: Sorry, is `Source()` just a placeholder? I am not able to import this class - am I missing an angular module?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169278/discussion-between-tomasz-kula-and-stefan-falk).

Comment: Hey, your **login.guard.ts** doesn't seem to have the correct syntax. Can you double check for me?